# Can I use static variable to pass data between activities instead of putExtra(Intent)?

Tags: android

I have two activities Activity_1 and Activity_2 respectively. Now I want to send data between these activities. I have two options :

1 - Using `Intent.putExtra()`
2 - Using static variable

So please, tell me what is the best approach to send data between these activities.

Comment: Yes you can use static varaiable but it might end up with a memory leak so passing data using intent is the best one .. aur ye questions ko downvote  pta ni kon kri ja ra  .. :P khair .. go for passing data in intent .. happy coding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static variable or pass variable via Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158608/static-variable-or-pass-variable-via-bundle)

Comment: nice explained @ Adeel Turk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you wish. You could even store the data into a database, and have your second `Activity` read it, if you want.

But `Android` offers a `intra-activity` communication model which is standard for all applications. Why not use it?

> So, Please tell me what is the better approach to send data between these activities.

You already know the answer for that.

You **won't** find a framework that advises to pass data between components via `static` variables.

---

As a personal note, I do not get why `public static` non-`final` fields are allowed in `java`.

---

**EDIT**

in my answer above I'm talking about dynamic data. If you are concerned with `constants`, then I don't see why you shouldn't use `public static final` fields.

Comment: I agree with you, but In some case, if need share complex data over 3 activities, we may use static. such as the case,  A->B, B->C, and both A, B and C can update the shared data. We can use intra-activity, but seems not convenient.  What's your idea on this case?